# React get object-values outside of .then // create map markers out of geocodes

Tags: reactjs, promise, maps, marker, geocode

I commented my code to make clear what should happen. I tried for hours to create the markers from the geocodes, however I can't seem to figure out how to extract the values from the promise. I fiddled with useState and useEffect, but neither worked.

```
const GMap = eventList => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.62919, lng: 7.3928 }}>
      {
          // Map through location-strings in eventList
          eventList.eventList.map(event => {
              // Get all geocodes
        Geocode.fromAddress(event.city).then(
          response => {
            const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log(lat, lng);
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
          }
        );
        return (
            // Create marker for every geocode (lat/lng pair)
          <Marker
            key={event._id}
            position={{
              lat: 51.62919, // How to insert the lat and lng values from response instead?
              lng: 7.3928
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

Thanks for helping out, it gets really frustrating by now to not solve this even tho it seems trivial at first.

Comment: Would you mind making a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const GMap = ({ eventList }) => {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    eventList.forEach(async event => {
      const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(event.city);
      const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;

      const marker = (
        <Marker
          key={event._id}
          position={{
            lat,
            lng
          }}
        />
      );

      setMarkers(prevMarkers => [...prevMarkers, marker]);
    });
  }, [eventList]);

  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.62919, lng: 7.3928 }}>
      {markers}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

```
eventList.forEach(async event => {
      const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(event.city);
```

We're going to loop over eventList and process the result as each time `Geocode.fromAddress` returns, rather than doing it in a `map`. The issue with a map is you are limiting yourself for the whole map to be processed first before displaying anything.  This method allows you to render markers as they are returned.

```
setMarkers(prevMarkers => [...prevMarkers, marker]);
```

Using `useState`'s callback, we use the previous `markers` and create a new array, appending the previous marker to it, so it slowly builds up as each `Geocode.fromAddress(event.city);` is returned.

A working CodeSandbox is here https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-paper-3eu03
I had to stub out `GoogleMap`, `Markers` and `Geocode`.

`Geocode`, to simulate the real-world, has a random `setTimeout` so you can see each result being loaded as they are ready.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly and the explanation is also very helpful and understandable!

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await to get a response from a Promise with synchronous:

```
eventList.eventList.map(async event => {
   // Get all geocodes
   const rs = await Geocode.fromAddress(event.city)

   // Path to location. this path example could be wrong
   const { lat, lng } = rs.results[0].geometry.location 

   return (
      <Marker
          key={event._id}
          position={{
              lat: lat,
              lng: lng
         }}
      />
   );
})
```

Comment: Thanks @jdn. It doesn't work yet though. Im getting multiple errors:

1. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Events`. 

2. react-dom.development.js:14793 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

3. event.js:46 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined (at event.js:46)

Comment: This as well:
4. index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.